# Regarding pytesseract

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, glob, python-tesseract

This code is not giving any output.I am learning python so kindly explain it in an easy manner

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('Users\Jatin\Desktop'): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
import pytesseract
for i in image_list:
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('i')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('Users\Jatin\Desktop'): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
```

In the above lines, you are iterating through all the files in the Desktop directory, opening them using PIL and appending the opened file to the list `image_list`

```
import pytesseract
for i in image_list:
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('i')))
```

In the above lines, you are iterating through the list of opened files and printing them on stdout. But nothing would be coming because instead of using the loop variable  `i`, you are passing the string `'i'` to the function `image_to_string`. You need to do:

```
for i in image_list:
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(i))
```

I haven't tested this but this is what looks wrong in your pasted code.